# Running parallel commands in bash

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have a situation where I have a directory "batches" containing several batch files:

```
one.txt
two.txt
...
seventy.txt
```

Each of these files needs to be processed by a python script as:

```
python processor.py --inputFile=batches/one.txt
```

My current implementation is as such:

```
for f in batches/$f
do
python processor.py --inputFile=batches/$f
done
```

I have hundreds of batches, so running all of them in parallel as

```
python processor.py --inputFile=batches/$f &
```

Is not feasible.

However,I think that running ~10 at a time shouldn't be a problem.

I'm aware that the syntax

```
{
python processor.py --inputFile=batches/batchOne.txt
python processor.py --inputFile=batches/batchTwo.txt
} &
{
python processor.py --inputFile=batches/batchThree.txt
python processor.py --inputFile=batches/batchFour.txt
}
```

Should give me a result similar to the one I wanted. However, are there any better solutions? Basically, given a command template, in my case

```
python processor.py --inputFile=batches/$1
```

And a list of batches, I'd like to control how many get executed at the same time.

I'm working on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: *＋1* for asking an bash question that actually has to do with programming and development (and is not tagged bash just because).

Answer (score 0):

### Try doing this to run 10 // executions :

```
parallel -j 10 command_line
```

### to install it

```
sudo apt-get install parallel
```

Comment: Does this allow me to specify custom parameters for each execution?

Comment: You have to do it programmaticaly

Answer (score 0):

`parallel` is a great tool, but not always you have option to install additional packages on a system. You can emulate `parallel` with bash `jobs`.

Here is a small example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for FILE in /tmp/*.sh;
do
    # count only running jobs. 
    JOBS=$(jobs -r | wc -l)
    while [[ ${JOBS} -ge 3 ]];
    do
        echo "RUNNING JOBS = ${JOBS} => WAIT"
        sleep 5 # too much, just for demo
    done
    echo "APPEND ${FILE} TO JOBS QUEUE [JOBS: ${JOBS}]"
    bash ${FILE} &
done

exit 0
```

**Test:**

```
$ grep '' /tmp/file*.sh
/tmp/file01.sh:sleep 8
/tmp/file02.sh:sleep 10
/tmp/file03.sh:sleep 5
/tmp/file04.sh:sleep 10
/tmp/file05.sh:sleep 8
/tmp/file06.sh:sleep 8

$ ./parallel.sh
APPEND /tmp/file01.sh TO JOBS QUEUE [JOBS: 0]
APPEND /tmp/file02.sh TO JOBS QUEUE [JOBS: 1]
APPEND /tmp/file03.sh TO JOBS QUEUE [JOBS: 2]
RUNNING JOBS = 3 => WAIT
APPEND /tmp/file04.sh TO JOBS QUEUE [JOBS: 2]
RUNNING JOBS = 3 => WAIT
APPEND /tmp/file05.sh TO JOBS QUEUE [JOBS: 1]
APPEND /tmp/file06.sh TO JOBS QUEUE [JOBS: 2]
```